# Is it possible to operate with the last of matching elements in XCTest?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I would like to tap the **last** [Play] button in my app, and I'm looking for something like

```
app.buttons["play"].lastMatch.tap()
```

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed this problem by writing a little extension

```
extension XCUIElementQuery {
    var lastMatch: XCUIElement { return self.element(boundBy: self.count - 1) }
}
```

after that, I can simply write code like this

```
app.buttons.matching(identifier: "play").lastMatch.tap()
```