# Multiple "More" buttons on iPad simulator. How do I narrow it down which one to click (either one)?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, ipad, xcuitest, gui-testing

I am trying to tap the `More` button in a XCUITest:

```
XCUIElement* moreKey = self.app.keys[@"more"];
[moreKey tap];
```

and on iPhone simulator it works fine, but on iPad simulator it crashes when I try to tap it:

```
Failed to Error Domain=com.apple.dt.xctest.ui-testing.error Code=10006 
"Multiple matching elements found for <XCUIElementQuery: 0x600000c51c20>
...
```

The issue is that it finds multiple instances of the "More" button on iPad (which, unlike iPhone, it has two of):

```
...}
    ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"more" IN identifiers'
      Output: {
        Key, 0x15e670f80, {{0.0, 1049.0}, {132.0, 60.0}}, identifier: 'more', label: 'numbers'
        Key, 0x15e678570, {{546.0, 1049.0}, {98.5, 60.0}}, identifier: 'more', label: 'numbers'
```

So, it doesn't seem to know which one to click.

I found similar questions, but for custom buttons, where solution was to make their identifier unique. That's not applicable for Apple's own "More" key, the identifier of which I do not control.

How do I fix it?
Can I apply `elementBoundByIndex:` here somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XCUIElement* moreKey = [self.app.keys[@"more"] firstMatch]` does the trick.

Comment: Assuming you want the first (what does tapping the second one do?), yep, you got it! A similar trick for if you wanted to tap the last match. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523441/2533443

Comment: Tapping the second does the same thing. iPad keyboard is just much bigger, so Apple includes second sets of More and Shift for Convenience. I didn't care which one to tap - I just wanted to fix it crashing when it was confused by two identical keys. Thanks!